# AJAX return jquery loop html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have HTML below being returned from Ajax success i am have been trying to do so far without success is to loop over the divs get the div id and then create a button for each on the jquery dialog box once the user clicks the button the HTML from within the div will be applied to a form.

the code below works but i have to filter out the content for each button but there is not always the same amount of divs there could be none for one person and 5 for another

i have tried to use jquery.each

i think someone would know how to loop thought these divs and create a button var for each one

HTML

```
<div class="target" id="1" >
        <p id="A1">04:00</p>
        <p id="A2">15:00</p>
        <p id="A3">00:16</p>
        <p id="A4">2</p>
        <p id="A5">10</p>
        <p id="A6">2</p>
        <p id="A7">10.73</p>
        <p id="A8">430.01</p>
        <p id="A9">0</p>
        <p id="NS">0</p>
        <p id="A10">0</p>
        <p id="A11" >0.73</p>
        <p id="B1" >448</p>
        <p id="B2" >found</p>
</div>
<div class="target" id="2" >
        <p id="A1">05:00</p>
        <p id="A2">13:00</p>
        <p id="A3">00:25</p>
        <p id="A4">3</p>
        <p id="A5">10</p>
        <p id="A6">2</p>
        <p id="A7">7.58</p>
        <p id="A8">263.71</p>
        <p id="A9">0</p>
        <p id="NS">0</p>
        <p id="A10">0</p>
        <p id="A11" >0.00</p>
        <p id="B1" >447</p>
        <p id="B2" >found</p>
</div>
<div class="target" id="3" >
        <p id="A1">05:00</p>
        <p id="A2">12:00</p>
        <p id="A3">01:00</p>
        <p id="A4">3</p>
        <p id="A5">06</p>
        <p id="A6">2</p>
        <p id="A7">6.00</p>
        <p id="A8">265.62</p>
        <p id="A9">0</p>
        <p id="NS">0</p>
        <p id="A10">0</p>
        <p id="A11" >0.00</p>
        <p id="B1" >446</p>
        <p id="B2" >found</p>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
   success:function(html){

var button1 = {
     text: "Edit "+$($(html).filter('#1').html()).filter('#A1').text(),click: function() {
                                var start = $($(html).filter('#1').html()).filter('#A1').text();
                                $("#start").val(start);
                                var finish = $($(html).filter('#1').html()).filter('#A2').text();
                                $("#finish").val(finish);
                                var breaktime = $($(html).filter('#1').html()).filter('#A3').text();
                                $("#break").val(breaktime);
                                var grade = $($(html).filter('#1').html()).filter('#A4').text();
                                $("#grade").val(grade);
},
var button2 = {
     text: "Edit "+$($(html).filter('#2').html()).filter('#A1').text(), click: function() { 
                                var start = $($(html).filter('#2').html()).filter('#A1').text();
                                $("#start").val(start);
                                var finish = $($(html).filter('#2').html()).filter('#A2').text();
                                $("#finish").val(finish);
                                var breaktime = $($(html).filter('#2').html()).filter('#A3').text();
                                $("#break").val(breaktime);
                                var grade = $($(html).filter('#2').html()).filter('#A4').text();
                                $("#grade").val(grade);
},
          }
```

Comment: You could use `each` but check the `length` before hand to make sure they have some?

Comment: This current method is insanity. Look at the structure of your code. Are you going to tell it to skip every 4 elements to find the start/finish/break/grade? The better way would be to have a `p` tag that has an id, then a `start/finish/break/grade` as `span` tags within that you can easily loop over. I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: ok that would be good i have been Ohgodwhy i know its a mess thats why i would like to find a better way if you would make a fiddle that would help

Comment: @Anthony `html`, appear to include _3_ `id="A1"` within same `document` ? Or, different `ajax` responses ? See `"id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document."` http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this it's probably best to use an object to define your data. Doing that should make your life a lot easier in terms of processing the data. After cleaning up your code I came up with the following object, which just requires that you pass it the html as a string and the id selector for your target. I'm not 100% positive this will work out of the bag, but it should. Here's a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d38b/45/) to demonstrate as well

```
var dataObject = function(html, id) {
    this.start = $(html).find(id).find('#A1').text();
    this.finish = $(html).find(id).find('#A2').text();
    this.breaktime = $(html).find(id).find('#A3').text();
    this.grade = $(html).find(id).find('#A4').text();
};
```

To instantiate it and get data just do the following

```
var button = new dataObject(html, "#1");
var temp_start = button.start
var temp_finish = button.finish
```

This practice is explained in depth at [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)